# Naming error in rails - creating API Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have my directory under `app/controllers` set up as such: `api/v1/sessions_controller.rb` I then have a `BaseController`: `api/v1/base_controller.rb`

I then set up each class to look as such:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class BaseController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json
      before_action :default_json

      protected

      def default_json
        request.format = :json if params[:format].nil?
      end

      def auth_only!
        render :json: {}, status: 401 unless current_user
      end
    end
  end
 end
```

And then Sessions:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < BaseController

      def create
        user = User.authenticate(params[:user_name], params[:password])
        if sign_in(user)
          set_up_cookie(user)
          render json: create_session_data, status: 201
        else
          invalid_user_crendentials
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The tests are set up the same way, for example the sessions test is:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::SessionsController do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  context "Create a session" do
    it "should NOT create a session" do
      post :create
      response.response_code.should == 401
    end
  end

end
```

The Error:

```
'<module:V1>': uninitialized constant Api::V1::BaseController (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting your naming slightly differently.

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  # code
end
```

and

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < BaseController
  # might need to name this Api::V1::BaseController
end
```

Comment: Same error: `'<module:V1>': uninitialized constant Api::V1::BaseController (NameError)`

Comment: did you also try adding the full class path for BaseController like in my comment? (just making sure before i look deeper)